# Can not do migragtion

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm doing site and I need to use EF. But When I start to do migration I have error U**nable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Category.tablets' of type 'ICollection'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.** 
This **Tablets.cs**

public class Tablets
{

```
public int id { set; get; }

public string name { set; get; }

public string shortDesc { set; get; }

public string longDesc { set; get; }

public string img  { set; get; }

public ushort price { set; get; }

public bool IsFavorite { set; get; }

public bool available { set; get; }

public int categoryID { set; get; }
public int availableOnSklad { get; set; }

public virtual Category Category1 { set; get; }
public virtual Category Category2 { set; get; }
public virtual Category Category3 { set; get; }

public virtual OrganyVplyvu OrganVplyvu1 { set; get; }
public virtual OrganyVplyvu OrganVplyvu2 { set; get; }
public virtual OrganyVplyvu OrganVplyvu3 { set; get; }

public virtual Hvoroby Hvoroba1 { set; get; }
public virtual Hvoroby Hvoroba2 { set; get; }
public virtual Hvoroby Hvoroba3 { set; get; }
```

}

**Category.cs**

```
public class Category
{
    public int id { set; get; }
    public string CategoryName { set; get; }
    //public string Description { set; get; }

    public ICollection<Tablets> tablets { set; get; }

}
```

**Hvoroby.cs**

```
 public class Hvoroby
    {
        public int id { set; get; }
        public string HvorobyName { set; get; }
        //public string Description { set; get; }
        public  ICollection<Tablets> tablets { set; get; }
    }
```

**OrganyVplyvu.cs**

```
public class OrganyVplyvu
    {
        public int id { set; get; }
        public string OrganName { set; get; }
        //public string Description { set; get; }
        public  ICollection<Tablets> tablets { set; get; }
    }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
 public class Startup
    {
        private IConfigurationRoot _config;
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;

        }
        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment hostenv)
        {
            _config = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(hostenv.ContentRootPath).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            Configuration.Bind("Data", new Config());

            services.AddControllersWithViews().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0).AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

            services.AddDbContext<AppDBContent>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddTransient<IAllTablets, TabletsReposetori>();
            services.AddTransient<ITabletsCategory, CategoryReposetori>();
            services.AddTransient<IAllOrganyVplyvu, OrganyVplyvuReposetori>();
            services.AddTransient<IAllHvoroby, HvorobyReposetory>();


            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment()) app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and **appsettings.json**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Source=MyDataSource;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;Trusted_Connection=True"
  }

}
```

I don't want to use [Not Mapped] because all fields are need. I search on the Internet and found out some solutions but I still don't understand how to fix it.

Comment: Can you also share your AppDBContent code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is because you have three navigation properties from `Tablets` to `Category`:

```cs
public virtual Category Category1 { set; get; }
public virtual Category Category2 { set; get; }
public virtual Category Category3 { set; get; }
```

But `Tablets` only has one `categoryID`. So how can EF determine if `categoryID` belongs to `Category1`, `Category2`, or `Category3` unless you specifically map it?

The same would apply to the `ICollection<Tablets> tablets` property of `Category` - is this the set of tablets where the `Category` is `Category1`, `Category2`, or `Category3`?

I'm not sure exactly what your needs are, but you could try to add these properties to `Tablets`:

```cs
public int category1ID { set; get; }
public int category2ID { set; get; }
public int category3ID { set; get; }
```

And remove the existing `categoryID` property

Then you would also need to add the corresponding collections to the `Category`:

```cs
public ICollection<Tablets> tablets1 { set; get; }
public ICollection<Tablets> tablets2 { set; get; }
public ICollection<Tablets> tablets3 { set; get; }
```

For each `Category` record, these collections would contain relationships where it mapped to the `Category1`, `Category2`, or `Category3` property of a `Tablets` record, respectively.

In order for this to work, you would probably need to manually map all these properties (either with attributes or in the `OnModelCreating` method, as the error mentions).

However, I think you would be better served by having a many-to-many join table between, such as `TabletCategories`, as this current design is likely to cause more issues for you down the road.

Something like this would let you specify additional information about a particular relationship (if needed):

```cs
public class TabletCategory
{
    public int TabletId { set; get; }
    public int CategoryId { set; set; }
}
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships